What is the glyph in hangul that best represents the close front unrounded vowel (the "ee" in "bee" or "see")?
What is the glyph in hangul that best represents the close front unrounded vowel?
In the English language, the close front unrounded vowel is usually written as "EE"
In the international phonetic alphabet (IPA), the close front unrounded vowel is written as i (this choice of visual glyph is common for words in the Spanish language).
Examples of English words that contain this phoneme are shown below:


see
bee
free
need
bean
sheep
seed
green
keep
feed
meet
heel
fee
eel
beetroot
peep
beetle
deep
knee
feel
jeep
freeze
seek
indeed
deer
peel
flee
breeze
cheese
teeth
week
tree
wean
disagree
sneeze
creep
kneel
sleep



Why not just read Korean phonology and Hangeul articles? Vowel [i] was written with glyphs ⟨I⟩, ⟨I⟩ since ancient times, and it is just English which has corrupted orthography / pronunciations. Hangeul letter for vowel [i] coincidentally looks the same as European letter, but Hangeul was created in 1443, before contacts with Europeans.

It is ㅣ (as in 이, 길, 치, for example) that sounds like the [I] or [i] sound.  There is no other vowel that has a similar sound, and no long and short sound.
All the words you listed will have this vowel, like 트리 (tree), 치즈 (cheese), and so on.  Some distinct English words with "i" or "ee" in them would transliterate to the same Korean word, like "meet" and "mitt" both becoming 미트.
